# Printing discord.Interaction throwing a error discord.py

Tags: python, button, discord.py

Discord recently added buttons to interact with buttons, I installed them with
`python3 -m pip install -U discord.py-message-components` as given in [discord.py buttons](https://discordpy-message-components.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Now when I am trying to print the Intercation object and get this error

```py
Ignoring exception in command test_command:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ibrahim/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 245, in test_command
    print(interaction, button)
  File "/home/ibrahim/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/interactions.py", line 96, in __repr__
    return f'<Interaction {", ".join(["%s=%s" % (a, getattr(self, a)) for a in self.__slots__ if a[0] != "_"])}>'
AttributeError: 'Interaction' object has no attribute '__slots__'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ibrahim/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 1062, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/ibrahim/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/ibrahim/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Interaction' object has no attribute '__slots__'
```

here is my code

```py
@commands.command(ignore_extra=True)
async def test_command(self, ctx, count:int):
    new_button = Button(label="test_button", custom_id = "009")
    message = await ctx.send("test", components = [[new_button]])

    def check_button(i: discord.Interaction, button):
        return i.author == ctx.author and i.message == message

    interaction, button = await bot.wait_for('button_click', check=check_button)

    print(interaction, button)

    await interaction.edit(content=count)
```

These are the things I imported

```py
import discord
from discord import Button, ButtonStyle, SelectMenu, SelectOption
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import check, Context, MemberConverter
```

Things that I have tried:

```py
from discord import Interaction
```

Why does this error happen and how do I fix this?

Comment: if anyone comes wondering when this will be fixed look at this issue that I made 
https://github.com/mccoderpy/discord.py-message-components/issues/12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, this is a bug. I saw it’s source code, and it did not define `__slots__`.

[This is the link to the Interaction class in GitHub](https://github.com/mccoderpy/discord.py-message-components/blob/main/discord/interactions.py#L56)

In the `__init__` part, it did not define `__slots__`.
In the `__repr__` part, it inserted `__slots__` in the `return` statement. So, it raised an `AttributeError`.

Can’t help you with that.

You can print some of the attributes, for example the author, button label, message etc… to print some information out.