# discordpy 2.0 interaction is a required argument that is missing

Tags: discord.py

```
@client.command(brief="Send a message with a button!")
async def button(ctx,interaction: discord.Interaction):
    view = discord.ui.View()
    style = discord.ButtonStyle.gray
    item = discord.ui.Button(style=style, label="Read the docs!", url="https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master")
    view.add_item(item=item)
    await interaction.response.send_message("This message has buttons!", view=view)
    await interaction.response.send_message(content="Hi", ephemeral=True)
```

discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: interaction is a required argument that is missing.

```
Actually i just want to send a message by intraction, but seem itwasn't work :(
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68223176/python-discord-bot-discord-ext-commands-errors-missingrequiredargument-number, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68806682/printing-discord-interaction-throwing-a-error-discord-py and https://www.google.com/search?q=interaction+is+a+required+argument+that+is+missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are confused about the basic concepts since your code is mixed up command and interaction stuffs. 
If you want to create button, you cannot write in the older command way like `@client.command`. You need to either use `application command` or `hybrid command` (which is a mix of interaction and command)
So, you should never have something like `(ctx: Context, interaction: Interaction)` together.
Also, classically, you need to create a `view` class and create a button inside this `view` class. Then you can attach this view to your message or embed when you send this to the user. 
And, if you want to respond to user multiple times in a application command, you cannot do that through `interaction.response` (only once). You can use `interaction.followup()` for later responses. [link](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=followup#discord.Interaction.followup)
For view examples, see file example under [this](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/master/examples/views)
For slash command (application command) example, see [this](https://gist.github.com/AbstractUmbra/a9c188797ae194e592efe05fa129c57f)

Comment: Maybe add a full example